# How to read UNIT ROOT TEST results obtained from EVIEWS? I mean what values do we study to interpret our result?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, unit-root, eviews

```
Null Hypothesis: D(OIL_PRICES) has a unit root
```

Exogenous: Constant
Lag Length: 0 (Automatic - based on SIC, maxlag=22)

```
        t-Statistic   Prob.*
```

Augmented Dickey-Fuller test statistic  -37.22113    0.0000
Test critical values:   1% level        -3.435299
    5% level        -2.863613
    10% level       -2.567923

*MacKinnon (1996) one-sided p-values.

Augmented Dickey-Fuller Test Equation
Dependent Variable: D(OIL_PRICES,2) 
Method: Least Squares
Date: 11/29/14   Time: 18:57
Sample (adjusted): 1/06/2009 2/28/2014
Included observations: 1267 after adjustments

Variable    Coefficient Std. Error  t-Statistic Prob.

D(OIL_PRICES(-1))   -1.042433   0.028006    -37.22113   0.0000
C   0.050065    0.043335    1.155289    0.2482

R-squared   0.522716        Mean dependent var  -0.003875
Adjusted R-squared  0.522339        S.D. dependent var  2.230622
S.E. of regression  1.541651        Akaike info criterion   3.705162
Sum squared resid   3006.510        Schwarz criterion   3.713283
Log likelihood  -2345.220       Hannan-Quinn criter.    3.708213
F-statistic 1385.413        Durbin-Watson stat  2.002267
Prob(F-statistic)   0.000000

Comment: I think I don't see some hypothesis testing in your result. There are some tests like the Dickey Fuller or KPSS test but you didn't give the results here. You probably have to state some where in EViews that you want to conduct such a test. Take a look at this youtube video. He explains how to do everything:
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-ePFfyGxz4I

Comment: I posted an answer to your question. Did it help you. Could you please reply, accept, or vote for it?

Comment: Could you replace your written text by posting simply a screen shot of your outputP This will be highly beneficial for others who have the same question and possibly come to this page.

Comment: Sir can you help me with guiding how to vote for your answer?

Comment: Hi Faiza, thank you for accepting my answer. However, for voting one needs at least 15 points and you have only 13 so far. I already up voted your question. So, I think I cannot do more. But maybe in the future when you have two points more you remember me and come back here to up vote. :)
But you can also go to some questions or answers of other users and just edit them. I think an accepted edit gives 2 points. ;) Or you can just ask another good question and somebody will up vote you there. This gives 5 points.

Comment: What would be your answer be if you get the following? The test statistic is −3.1056 Now you need to compare this with the critical values under H0 The critical values are given with: 1%:−3.435299
5%:−2.863613
10%:−2.567923.

Comment: Watch the following video for an easy and quick explanation! https://youtu.be/65g6D4bICQY Cheers

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You conducted a Augmented Dickey Fuller test. The hypothesis of this test are $H_0$: "Process has unit root" vs. $H_1$: "Process has no unit root". The test statistic is $-37.22113$. Now you need to compare this with the critical values under $H_0$. The critical values are given with:

$ 1\%: -3.435299 \\
  5\%: -2.863613 \\
 10\%: -2.567923.$

Since your test statistic is much lower than all of the critical values you can reject $H_0$ at a significance level $ \ \ <1\% $. So you can conclude with a very low probability of making an error that your time series has no unit root. So, you can reject $H_0$.

Comment: Many Thanks for supporting me, this has let me clear my question up to some extent...:)

Comment: alternatively you look at your p-value. if your p-value is less than 0.05, reject your null hypothesis at 5% significance level.

Answer (score 0):

If t* > ADF crtitical value, ==>  accept null hypothesis, i.e., unit root
exists..
mean data is non stationary

If t* < ADF critical value, ==>   reject null hypothesis, i.e., unit root does not exist.
mean data is stationary